# Why don't i see the deleted rows in SalesForce object

Tags: query, isdeleted

We create some object in saleseforce named Custom_kpi__c. When we delete the rows in this object we can't see that using `select id , isdeleted from Custom_kpi__c where isDeleted=true`.
But we see that in salesforce recycle bin.
How do we can see the deleted rows in query?
And why isdeleted field is vary good work in other objects using `select id , isdeleted from Object_name where isDeleted=true`?

Answer (score 2):

[You need to append "ALL ROWS" to your query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) like this:

```
select id , isdeleted from Custom_kpi__c where isDeleted=true ALL ROWS
```

Also, you can't do that in Developer Console Query Editor.

Comment: I use this in Developer Console and Data Loader and have mistake in both cases: "All Rows Not allowed " - in Data Loader and "Unknown error parsing query" in Developer Console. Where do i must do this query?

Comment: you can use in:
* Apex Code (Apex Class)
* Anonymous Execution Window

Comment: We cannot use this in work base, because we don't have Global admin rights

Comment: Try Anonymous Execution Window

Comment: We need use this in QV code for update qvd files. Query "select id , isdeleted from Object_name where isDeleted=true" work with all others objects well in code. Why it doesn't  work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the "QueryAll()" API call? Using the regular "Query()" call won't allow you to retrieve delete records. See the API documentation on the "QueryAll()" API call here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_queryall.htm

Comment: we used option QueryAll in QlikView connector and have error ALL ROWS not allowed in this context

Comment: your link doesn't work

Comment: @Oleg - Updated the link. Please update as answer to help others.

Comment: How can i use QueryAll in QlikView code?